# fourier transform is a bijective transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation

[Fourier transformation picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDFY.png)

How to show that Fourier transform (please find picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDFY.png)) is a bijective transformation?

For injective, I did the following. Is it right?
$${F}_1(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f_1(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx}$$
$${F}_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f_2(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx}$$
Suppose  that ${F}_1(x)={F}_2(x)$, then
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f_1(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f_2(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx}$$
$$=>\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f_1(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx}-\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{f_2(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx}=0$$
$$=>\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}({f_1(x)-f_2(x))e^{-i\omega x}dx}=0$$
$$=>f_1(x)=f_2(x)$$

How can we show that it is surjective?

Comment: On $L^2$, the integral definition of the Fourier transform may not converge, so there's rather more to the proof than what you have shown.

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: Well, proving that the Fourier transform is bijective on $L^2$ is actually a fairly long and technical proof if I recall correctly. What facts do you have available? Do you at least know the definition of the Fourier transform on $L^2$? This is typically defined by a density argument using the fact that $L^1 \cap L^2$ is dense in $L^2$, and the fact that we can calculate the Fourier transform of a function in $L^1 \cap L^2$ using the usual integral definition.

Comment: Injectivity is a consequence of [Plancherel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem): since $\|f_1 - f_2\|_2 = \|\hat{f_1} - \hat{f_2}\|_2$, the Fourier transforms of two $L^2$ functions are equal a.e. iff the original functions are equal a.e.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the functions involved are nice enough (which appears to be done implicitly in the attached text anyway), this follows from the [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem), which provides an explicit inverse for the Fourier transformation.